# Symfony dependency injection or service location for Repositories in PHPUnit tests

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit, repository-pattern, api-platform.com

I'm writing a test for my code in [API Platform](https://api-platform.com) (built on Symfony 5) and PHPUnit.

I've created a base testcase named `TestContext` that extends `ApiTestCase`. All my tests classes will extend `TestContext` to reuse shared testing boilerplate code.

I'm also trying to use dependency injection (or service location) to resolve the Repository class, so I can access them in all the child classes.

What would be the cleanest, easiest and best-practice way to have access to my Repositories in my test classes?

Comment: Technically you're looking for service location, not dependency injection. Could you please process your edit queue so I can submit an edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to inject the Repository for the API tests I have a src/Test/BaseApiTest.php

```
namespace App\Test;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Hautelook\AliceBundle\PhpUnit\ReloadDatabaseTrait;

class BaseApiTestCase extends ApiTestCase
{
    use ReloadDatabaseTrait;

    protected ?EntityManagerInterface $em;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();

        $this->em = $kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
    }
}
```

Then for the test in my root `tests` directory I access it as he following:

```
//tests/UserRessourceTest.php
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Test\BaseApiTestCase;

class UserResourceTest extends BaseApiTestCase
{
    public function testDeleteAccount(): void
    {
        ...
        /** @var User $deletedUser */
        $deletedUser = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneById($user->getId());
        ...
    }
}
```

This works well for most of my cases. I hope it will work for yours ;)